# How do I restore a non-system hard drive using Time Machine under OSX?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I dropped one of the external drives on my Mac Pro and it started making noises... so I bought a replacement drive. No biggie, that's why I have Time Machine, right?

So now that I have the new drive up and initialized, how do I actually restore the drive from backup?

Time Machine is intuitive when it comes to restoring the *system drive* or restoring individual folders/files on the same literal device, but I'm a bit stuck in how to *properly* restore an entire drive that is *not* the boot drive.

I saw one suggestion to use the same volume name as the old drive and then go into Time Machine. Haven't tried that since the information is unconfirmed.

For now, I just went to the Time Machine volume, found the latest backup folder for that volume, and I'm copying the files via Finder. Of couse, I expect this to work just fine, but I feel like I'm missing something if that's the "proper" way to do this.

*Edit 2014-06:* woudldn't you know it, I had the same thing happen again, had the same question, and happened to run across my question here! lol... Just to confirm, I *did* have to give the volume on the new drive the same name as the volume being restored, otherwise Time Machine wouldn't show the history of the old drive.

Comment: For more details, see this related question: http://superuser.com/q/65146/98260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start the *Time Machine* viewer, go back in time one step, and select your computer name in the Finder, you should see all the computer's volumes you have backups for.

Comment: I'm nearly finished copying the files, but I checked and did find the old drive in the list of volumes a few history steps back! Seems perfectly reasonable in retrospect, but wasn't expecting entire *old disconnected volumes* to show up in the history, only old folders and files.